# How to deal with element in tuple

Tags: c++, tuples

I'm about to iterate the element , to perform some action dependet on different condition.Nonetheless, It seems that my code cannot compile by vs, I know that my code is not correct, I alse notice that the similar question have been answered in previous question. Unfortunately , It's as the answer as my demanded.
the following code is attched in the below section.

```cpp
template<typename TupleType, std::size_t...Index>
std::string XXX::GetInfo(TupleType infoCollect,std::string& finalStr, std::integer_sequence<std::size_t, Index...>) {
    if constexpr (((std::is_same<decltype(std::get<Index>(infoCollect)), std::string>::value) ,...)) {
        //finalStr + =std::get<Index>(infoCollect);
    } else {
        if constexpr(((std::is_fundamental_v<decltype(std::get<Index>(infoCollect))>,...)) {
            //finalStr += std::to_string(std::get<Index>(infoCollect));
        }
    }
    return finalStr;
}
```

and call to function 'GetInfo' in a member function:

```
auto additionalCollect=std::make_tuple("ss","dd",3);
std::string additionalstr={};
using Indices = std::make_integer_sequence<std::size_t, std::tuple_size<decltype(additionalCollect)>::value>;

std::apply([this](auto tupleEle, std::string &finalAdditional)noexcept->std::string {

    GetInfo(tupleEle, finalAdditional, Indices());
    return finalAdditional;
}, std::make_tuple(additionalCollect,additionalstr));
```

can someone provide assistacne for me,thx man!

Comment: Show an example of how you call GetInfo and the result you expect, and what errors VS produces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument `"ss"` is not `std::string` type, rather a `const char*`. Also you could implement in a much simpler way, without using `std::integer_sequence`.

[See live online in godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/O54NLq)

```
template <typename T>
void GetSingleInfo(std::string& finalStr, const T& t)
{
    // for string-like types
    if constexpr (std::is_convertible_v<T, std::string_view>)
        finalStr += t;
    else if (std::is_arithmetic_v<T>)
        finalStr += std::to_string(t);
}
```

and call function `GetInfo` using `std::apply`:

```
auto additionalCollect = std::make_tuple("ss", "dd"s, 3, 0.5, "bb"sv);
auto additionalStr = std::string{};

auto GetInfo = [&additionalStr](const auto&... args) {
    // c++17 fold expression
    (GetSingleInfo(additionalStr, args), ...);
};
std::apply(GetInfo, additionalCollect);
```

Comment: Hey man, above first, Thanks you for your answer， and then the code can be well compiled by GCC , but it's not be compiled by msvc , and prompt for error to code is that 'typename is not allowed'. it seems that the '<typename... Args>' in lambda is belong to the extension from GCC, it's not allowed in msvc. I'm also notice that that scenario can be replaced by auto&&... args, however, i didnot know that  auto&&...args used in std::forward. can you give an answer to this question , thx guy.

Comment: @Savner_Dig Just using `std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)`, and notice that template lambda is a c++20 feature, msvc is not implemented yet.

Comment: Thanks! It's now proper to compile!